# Drawing a heatmap for 2 columns: Time Vs. Electricity

Tags: r, heatmap, pheatmap

I have dataframe of 2 columns; where first column holds data as d/m/y h:m (for one year) while second column holds electricity meter reading. For instance:

```
Date.Time           X
13/12/2014 12:00    164
13/12/2014 12:30    278
13/12/2014 13:00    159
13/12/2014 13:30    302
13/12/2014 14:00    249
13/12/2014 14:30    196
.
.
.
14/12/2014 00:00    137
14/12/2014 00:30    71
14/12/2014 01:00    116
14/12/2014 01:30    92
```

I want to draw heatmap for each day for each half an hour. I tried `pheatmap`, `heatmap.2` and `heatmap.3` but error message is `x' must be a numeric matrix`. I am just wondering can I draw a map with these two columns or should I arrange the data first to one row presenting one day data like:

```
day         12:00 12:30 1:00 1:30
13/12/2014    164  278  159 302 ...
14/12/2014    160  178  129 602 ...
```

Any suggestion please? Thank you!

Comment: This should be easy to do with ggplot2's `geom_tile()` if you make separate columns for date and time. Then do something like `ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=time, fill=X)) + geom_tile()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to change the data from long to wide format; you just need to split out the date and time so you can use them on separate axes. Here's what I did with some toy data:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Make some toy data with a year's worth of observations on every half hour
df <- data.frame(date.time = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), to = as.POSIXct("2015-12-31"), by=30))
df$X <- rnorm(nrow(df), 100, 25)

# Create separate vectors for date and time, preserving date/time format
df$date <- as.Date(df$date.time)
df$time <- strftime(df$date.time, format="%H:%M:%S")

# Now use ggplot2's geom_tile() to make the heatmap
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=date, fill=X)) + geom_tile()
print(p)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time and writing here. I have few issues with this code which I am trying to resolve, 1st: the 'time' variable provides me a vector in this format: '00:00:00', '00:00:30', '00:01:00', '00,01:30'... which means data is collected after each 30 seconds but in my case data is each after 30 minutes. 2nd thing is, I want to see the heatmap corresponding to each day, for instance, i want to visualize energy usage after each half an hour for one day, then second row for 2nd day. I am sorry if I could not make it clear.you can ask me if its not clear. Thanks again

Comment: The time intervals in the toy data don't matter for how the code will work on your data. If you want toy data with 30-min intervals, just change the last bit of the first line to `by=30*60`. Anyway, if you have observations for every 30 minutes in a data frame called `df`, then `df$time <- strftime(df$date.time, format="%H:%M:%S")` should return the same. And `aes(x=time, y=date, fill=X)` will do what you describe: days as rows, time slots as columns, fill color based on values of `X`.

Comment: I just installed R version 3.2.2 and intsalled `ggplot2` but package `ggplot` is not working with this version :-( Do you have any idea whats wrong with this. I don't want to switch to the last version because `ddplyr` was not working there. any clue?

Comment: No, sorry, can't help you there.

Comment: It,s Okay. I am trying to find the solution. Thank you for your help. I appreciate.